# jquery auto complete plugin not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I am trying to implement auto complete feature in my rails application.I am able to get print the array that i passed for the autocomplete.but the auto complete is not working.

My controller code:

```
 def new
 @release = Release.new
 @names = User.all(:select => "name").map { |x| x.name } 
    respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
    end
end
```

My view code:

```
 %td.grid.full_panels
    -table_panel "Assign Testers" do
      %table
        %th Name
        = form.label :tester_tokens, "Testers" 
        = form.text_field :tester_tokens
:javascript
   var data="#{escape_javascript @names.to_json}";    
= javascript_include_tag :defaults,:cache => true
```

My application.js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
alert (data);
$('#release_tester_tokens').autocomplete(data);
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the error console in Firefox, Safari or Chrome? would you mind to post only your HTML and Javascript code (alternativly is just need add a link to http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: Hi I did not not get any error in IE

Comment: Have you enabled the option "Show javascript error" (or similar) ?

Comment: I didn't get any java script error

Comment: Then please, post your HTML and Javascript code at http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autocomplete plugin actually expects an object literal with options when initialized.

To set the data, use the [source](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source) property:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert (data);
    $('#release_tester_tokens').autocomplete({
        source: data
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Diedier, thanks a lot for answering me. with the modification u gave if i set the data variable locally, data="sramya","scharron"];  then the auto complete is happening. its not happening if I pass it in json format through the view file its not working. Please hel pme out here.

Comment: You might to parse the JSON generated to transform it into a javascript object with `$.parseJSON(data)` ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/))

Comment: Hi Didier, I changed the code to $.parseJSON(data);
alert (data);
$('#release_tester_tokens').autocomplete({source:data}); The data is displayed as ["ann","bob"].Still auto complete doesn't work.

Comment: Works for me: [http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/ytFNr/](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/ytFNr/). Without seeing what you really get in `data` it is difficult to guess what is your problem...

Comment: hi Didier the problem is in ur example the data is enclosed in quotes(data='["ann","bob"]'.In mine its not.The data =["ann","bob"].Is there a command to convert it to the above one

Comment: I'm really not familiar with the ruby syntax. If you have `var data = ["a", "b", "c"];` it should work without parsing json (it's already an array) and work in autocomplete. Does your element `'#release_tester_tokens'` exists when you call autocomplete ? What is the result of `alert($('#release_tester_tokens').length)` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6194/discussion-between-didier-g-and-ramya)